# Input text form, using javascript to clear and restore form contents problem

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this line of HTML

```
<input type="text" name="addQty" size="1" 
       class="addQty" value="0" 
       onclick="$(this).val('')" 
       onblur="itmQtyChk($(this).val())" />
```

the `itmQtyChk` function does this:

```
function itmQtyChk( qty ) {
    if( qty == "") {
        $(this).val("0");
    } else {
        $(this).val(qty);
    }
 }
```

My problem is I want it to return the original value to the input text if they exit the field and don't change anything, but it is not working.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Your question is not clear. What original value?

Comment: It starts out with the value being 0, when you click on the input box I want it to clear the contents (or value) of the input field, and let the user type in a new value. If they do not type in a new value I would like the input field to be repopulated with the value before it was cleared.

Comment: @Darin, presumably the `value="0"` as in, perhaps edited into, the question)?

Comment: you are clearing the input every time the user clicks in it *even if they've previously entered a non-zero value* or even if it already has focus and they are trying to use the mouse to help edit the value already there. Instead I'd suggest clearing it `onfocus` and only clear it if the current value is "0".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this` in `itmQtyChk` function is not referring to the input but to the `window` object.

Change the function to accept the input as parameter:

```
function itmQtyChk(input) {
    if (input.val() == "") {
        input.val("0");
    }
    // the else part is not needed
}
```

with the `onblur` event also:

```
onblur="itmQtyChk($(this))"
```

Comment: Thank you this works! I suppose changing it back to 0 is ok if they don't type in a new number instead of changing it to the number that was there before. I think I might like it better this way.

Answer (score 1):

Check this fiddle, it has lots of room for improvement, but it can help you:

http://jsfiddle.net/eDuKr/1/

```
$(function(){

    var cacheQty;

    $('.addQty').click(function(){
        cacheQty = $(this).val();
        $(this).val('');

    }).blur(function(){
        if ($(this).val() === ''){
            $(this).val(cacheQty);
        }else{
            cacheQty = $(this).val();
        }
    });   
});
```